# Why is the memory limit exceeded?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was doing the "Sort Characters By Frequency" problem on the [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/) [online judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming#Overview).

Why does this happen?

#### Code

```
class Solution {

    public:
        struct Node {
            int freq;
            char ch;
        };

        static bool lambda(struct Node a, struct Node b) {
            return a.freq > b.freq;
        }

        string frequencySort(string s) {
            if(s.size() == 0)
                return "";

            string res = "";
            vector<Node> nums(256);

            for(char c : s) {
                nums[(int)c].ch = c;
                nums[(int)c].freq++;
            }

            std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), Solution::lambda);

            char c;
            for(int i=0; nums[i].freq > 0; i++) {
                c = nums[i].ch;
                while(nums[i].freq--) {
                    res = res + c; // If I replace this line with res += c, it gets accepted!
                }
            }

            return res;
        }
};
```

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `res = res + c;` and `res += c;`?

Comment: More information as well.

Comment: Probably the string is huge?

Comment: If `char` is `signed` and if you get "extended" characters as input (i.e. characters whose encoding is larger than 127) then the expression `(int)c` will cause sign-extension and you will have a out-of-bound index.

Comment: Off-topic "fix-my-code" question. Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run the code step by step.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but if `char` is signed, and the string contains characters with the top bit set, you will index outside the vector.

Comment: Cannot dive now into algorithmic problem unfortunately. Please, check that your `for` loop condition is what you really intended to have. Loop body is suspicious as well. Please, check it thoroughly. Note that chat can is signed (not important if it's always latin letter). Unrelated: consider using `std::pair` and reverse iterators so you can solve it without your struct and lambda.

Comment: You might also want to consider using string::reserve() and overload (5) of [string::appen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: He probably won't be able to reproduce his problem in a sensible time.  It will only happen with very large inputs, and it's going to be really hard for a new programmer to realize what it is going on at all.

Comment: @n.m. But he says that if he does `res += c;` it works.

Comment: In addition to all of the suggestions mentioned above, since I don't see the input `string s` (in `string frequencySort(string s)`) being modified, consider passing it by `const` reference: `string frequencySort(string const& s)`. That avoids copying that whole `string`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> res = res + c; // If I replace this line with res += c, it gets Accepted!
> ```

`string operator+(string&, string&)` operator copies the arguments into a new string object. You then copy this temporary return value into `res` - which may also involve copying into a new, larger buffer. Unless C++11 is enabled, in which case move assignment will be used, so the latter potential allocation + copy is avoided.

`string& operator+=(const string&)` does not create a new string object. It modifies the existing string buffer in-place - unless a larger buffer is needed, in which case reallocation cannot be avoided.

So, `res += c` avoids creation of temporary buffers in dynamic memory. If the string is large enough, doubling the number of simultaneously used copies can roughly double the peak memory use of the program. Also, the extra temporary allocations may increase the fragmentation of dynamic memory space, which increases the overhead of dynamic memory management. These two factors may cause the memory limit given for the program to be exceeded.